# Google analytics - not showing up last year metrics

Tags: google-analytics

I had google analytics set up for one of my client sites in 2014 which was using Oracle CMS. We migrated the site to a new Drupal based CMS and changed the site google analytics to use a new UA code(in 2015). We are seeing page views and other out of box metrics that comes up with the google analytics in the new UA code profile. But the old UA code profile does not show the historical information for the time period we were using the old UA code(2014 timeframe). What could be going on there? How would the historical data go missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology seems a bit off - "profiles" (which are now called "views") do not have their own UAID (tracking ids are assigned per property, and each property might have one or more data views. Each account has at least one property).

The simplest explanation is that somebody deleted  the view (profile) from the old tracking id and created a new view; since views start empty you'd be able to select earlier timeframes, but not see any data.

If this was 2014 there is a pretty good chance that the change history in the account setting was already available, so you'd be able to check if somebody deleted a data view. If that is indeed the case then you are out of luck, this is not recoverable.